# How can I break if an integer is between a range of integers

Tags: assembly, mips

For the example, I get an integer of an ASCII number. I want to determine if it is lower case. Ex (between 97 and 122).

Is there a way to break if a number falls between a range of numbers? I'm fairly new to Assembly so conditionals are unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Did you try writing it in C and looking at the disassembly?

Comment: I don't currently have knowledge in C.

Answer (score 2):

Set one register if the number in question is below the lower bound, then set another if it's above the upper bound. Take the logical AND of the two registers (this can go into one of the registers you've just used, since you won't need them anymore), and branch on the result.

Let's use the argument registers `$a0` for the number you wish to test, `$a1` for the lower bound, and `$a2` for the upper bound; and the temporary registers `$t1` and `$t2`.

```
slte $t0, $a1, $a0    # Sets $t0=1 if $a1 < $a0, otherwise $t0=0
slte $t1, $a0, $a2    # Sets $t1=1 if $a0 < $a2, otherwise $t1=0

and  $t0, $t1, $t0    # Sets $t0=1 if $a1 < $a0 < $a2, otherwise $t0=0
```

Now `$t0` equals 1 if and only if the variable is within the required range, so you can use a `beq` or `bne` to branch as desired. Think carefully about your bounds - you may want `slt` instead of `slte`.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to how I set a register depending on a conditional.

Comment: `sle $rd, $rs, $rt`
Will set `$rd` to 1 if `$rs` is less than `$rt`